# Python CGI Showing 500 internal server error

Tags: python, .htaccess, cgi

I'm a python developer, but when i'm putting my file inside a cgi-bin directory
and running it through my browser its showing 500 internal server error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8"
print

print "Hello World!"
```

This is my test.py.
Filelocation : http://mywebsite.com/cgi-bin/test.py

.htaccess file :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 Options +ExecCGI AddHandler cgi-script cgi py
 Options +ExecCGI SetHandler cgi-script
```

Please give some suggestion!

Comment: What does your error.log say?

Comment: there's no entry of this error in error_log

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the server set up is OK the most likely problem is forgetting to set the python file to executable after copy to the cgi-bin directory.

Comment: i did chmod +x test.py but no result.

Comment: Try chmod a+rx test.py

Comment: Or try to set chmod 755.